# Visual Studio trying to add parent directory files into project located in subfolder

Tags: visual-studio

I am getting some code to build and debug in VS2008. Basically the project is located within a sub folder, and it is trying to access .ascx files in a folder that is two folders up within the hierarchy. I.e.: project is in //website/source/current/projectfolder and it tries to access a file in //website/usercontrols.

How do I get those files into my work space in the solution folder and so the application can actually build? Also is there a way to do so by adding the entire usercontrols folder as opposed to file by file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add an existing folder, but you can certainly add multiple existing items at one time.  When you choose "Add Existing Items", you can select multiple files in the dialog.  By default, this will copy the item into your project directory if it lies outside of it.

If you don't want to add the actual files to your project as a copy, you can add them as a link.

Add a new folder to your project.  Then choose "Add Existing Item...", browse to the folder several levels up, select all the files in the folder that you wish to add, and click the little dropdown button on the "Add" button.  Then choose "Add as link".

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4343/9132009103548pm.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4343/9132009103548pm.png)

The files will be linked into your project but not physically copied.  Make sure that your namespaces are correct.